# crm 2011 N:N relationship - disabled adde existing button, why?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have N:N relationship between case (incident) and my custom entity. 
The relationship was created under case entity but I thought it doesn't matter.

Now when I go to the case and want to add existing entity to the subgrid it works fine. but when I go to my custom entity and navigate to the related cases (via navigation pane) the button "Add new Case" is not visible and "Add Exisiting Case" is disabled. Can I enable this one? I'd like to connect cases and my custom entities from both sides. Is it possible?

Comment: Does your user have create and append permission on both entities?

Comment: yes, I'm logged in as an administrator and it doesn't help

Comment: If you permissions are fine then try checking that the buttons were not messed up in the Ribbon Editor (you could hide the out of the box buttons and add new ones, even with the same icons, for instance)